# Call correct pip in pyvenv environment python3.4

Tags: python, virtualenv

I installed a new pyvenv environment with the following commands:

```
python3.4 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
```

However, when I call `which pip`, I get the following: `/usr/bin/pip`. Apparently, the system wide pip installation is still used. If I look at the pyvenv documentation, it states the following:

> Changed in version 3.4: Installs pip by default, added the
>   --without-pip and --copies options

And this is correct, when trying to install pip in my activated environment, I get the following:

> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./env/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages

How do I make sure that when I call pip in my activated environment, pyvenv pip is called?

Comment: @CollinAnderson That gives no reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having a similar issue, I asked my webhost (WebFaction) and got an excellent response. The [Understanding pyvenv and pip in virtual environments with python 3.4 and above](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/17074/understanding-pyvenv-and-pip-in-virtual-environments-with-python-34-and-above) page is summarized below.

It seems that you don't have to worry about which pip your virtual environment is using. As long as your virtual environment is active, any packages will be installed in it, regardless of which pip is used.

One thing about Python 3.4 virtual environments is that if the package does not support [Python's new "wheel" package format](http://pythonwheels.com/), the package will not install inside the virtual environment directory. It will still maintain a connection with the virtual environment however.

Because of this strangeness, I opted to just use virtualenv instead of pyvenv-3.4 and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you (and I in my previous answer) were seeing the effects of a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue17732). Everything seems to be working in the newer versions of pyvenv-3.4.

```
$ pwd
~/test
$ pyvenv-3.4 myenv
$ source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv)$ which pip
~/test/myenv/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed on Ubuntu 14.10.

And if you installed python 3.4 by the following command on Centos6.

`yum install http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/python34u-3.4.2-1.ius.centos6.x86_64.rpm`

You should reopen a new terminal (or relogin your system).

It works for me. Good luck.